# Could not locate clojure/math/numeric_tower__init.class or clojure/math/numeric_tower.clj on classpath

Tags: clojure, leiningen

On a fresh lein install, when I start the repl via `lein repl` and enter into the repl:

`(use 'clojure.math.numeric-tower)`

It throws an error:

`FileNotFoundException Could not locate clojure/math/numeric_tower__init.class or clojure/math/numeric_tower.clj on classpath.`

I'm new to Clojure so I don't really know how to fix this.

Lein version: Leiningen 2.7.1 (lein -v)

Clojure version: 1.8.0 ( (clojure-version) )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `[org.clojure/math.numeric-tower "0.0.4"]` to the project's dependencies (in project.clj) and restart the repl.

Comment: It's a simple script. Not really a project. Do I need to keep a project.clj file?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate to add dependencies dynamically to classpath!

Comment: If you use lein repl then project.clj makes your life easier, but you can start the repl without the project.clj file